# stream_context_set_params not works with ssh2.sftp wrapper

Tags: php, sftp, libssh2

I want to use functionality like [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-notification-callback.php). Please check the code bellow

```
function notify (
    $notification_code,
    $severity,
    $message,
    $message_code,
    $bytes_transferred,
    $bytes_max
) {
    echo "Runned \n";
};

$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_set_params($ctx, array('notification' => 'notify'));
$ssh_connection = ssh2_connect('myhost');
ssh2_auth_password($ssh_connection, 'login','pass');
$sftp_resource = ssh2_sftp($ssh_connection);
$data = file_get_contents("ssh2.sftp://{$sftp_resource}/path/to/big/file",
            false, $ctx);
```

I expect that my notify function will be called at least once.
Actually, the same code works for ftp wrappers

```
function notify (
    $notification_code,
    $severity,
    $message,
    $message_code, 
    $bytes_transferred,
    $bytes_max
) {
    echo "Runned \n";
};

$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_set_params($ctx, array('notification' => 'notify'));
$scheme = 'ftp';
$data = file_get_contents("{scheme}://username:password@host:port/path/to/file",
            false, $ctx);
```

And it works fine! The notify function is called many times.
I try to use sftp wrapper like this

```
$data = file_get_contents("ssh2.sftp://username:password@host:port/path/to/big/file",
            false, $ctx);
```

And it isn`t works too.
Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure but I think that's one of the concepts of ssh. The crypted connection handling is done by the ssh lib, not by php. Therefore no notifications. Will investigate if the said is true

Comment: Yep. Seems it should not work for ssh and ssh wrappers(scp, tunnel, sftp, etc)

Comment: Yes. I've tested it too. Btw, I found a segfault in the php-ssh2 extension. :| ... I'm currently looking in the extension code to find out why notification is not called. Either it is by design or just not implemented

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ssh2 extension doesn't support notfication callbacks. I don't know if this is by design or just not implemented, but the extensions code is missing calls to functions like:

From (PHP-5.4.10) /ext/standard/ftp_fopen_wrapper.c, line 573:

```
php_stream_notify_progress_init(context, 0, file_size);
```

A **workaround**, which I've not tested yet might be to use `ftps://` (FTP over ssl). It should fit your security needs and - as the code looks like - will support notifications as ftp. In detail, it uses the same urlwrapper as ftp.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a recent commit to [phpseclib's pure PHP SFTP stream wrapper](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net) adds support for notifications:

https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/commit/a47c1c39809a18b870b3812ce9ab84c7bd55efdd