# PHP sftp - can i get download/upload speed?

Tags: php, pear, pecl

Is it possible to get information on download and upload speed using standard PHP tools (ssh2_sftp)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18690550/1597430

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$start = time();

$sftp->get('filename', 'local/filename'); //gets the file
$size = $sftp->size('filename'); //gives the size of the file.

$timeTakenInSeconds = time() - $start;
echo sprintf('Bytes/second: %d', $size / $timeTakenInSeconds);
```